# I snapped my micro SD card into 8 pieces before throwing it away. Should I be worried that someone can get my data?

Tags: data-recovery, sensitive-data-exposure, ssd, flash-memory, destruction

The card was a 16gb SanDisk micro SD card (monolithic).

Comment: It has a silicon chip in it, did you destroy also the chip?

Comment: I think I did because silicon glitter fell out when I snapped it?

Comment: *"Silicon Glitter"* . I assure you that is **not** what you saw!

Comment: Most of the time, throwing away an entire micro-SD in a pile of trash makes your data vanish forever... It's not that easy to find a micro-SD if you don't know it is there...

Answer (score 2):

Should you be worried? **No!**

Is it technically possible, probably.

Here is an example SD card Xray, although not specifically a SanDisk.

[image: SD card Xray]

The memory chips are very small and unless you broke that specific memory chip, it's possible to rebuild and recover the data. However, this is a pretty difficult undertaking and not one that most people or even most forensic labs will do, although it is possible.